# How do you establish single node Hadoop instance on AWS using Apache Whirr?

Tags: amazon-ec2, hadoop, amazon-web-services, cloudera

I am attempting to run a single-node instance of Hadoop on Amazon Web Services using Apache Whirr. I set `whirr.instance-templates` equal to `1 jt+nn+dn+tt`. The instance starts up fine. I am able to create directories, but when I try to `put` files, I get a `File could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1 error`. When I do a `hadoop fsck /` I get a `Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` error. Does anyone know what is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I made the experience that whirr does not always start all services reliable. It sounds like the namenode started (the namenode is responsible for storing directory information) but the datanode did not start (the datanode stores the data).

Try running

```
hadoop dfsadmin -report
```

to see if a datanode is available.

If not: often it helps to restart the cluster.